Have black screen after build game on web gl
Good day.
Everything works fine for me on the unity stage, but as soon as I start the game, after the unity screensaver I get a black screen with an interface, what to do, please help.


My console
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at ra (v2:sourcemap:1:96881)
    at v2:sourcemap:1:110441
v2:sourcemap:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at window.loadEnvironmentPromise.window.loadEnvironmentPromise.Promise.then.t (v2:sourcemap:1:110561)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at v2:sourcemap:1:110507
index.html:822 Live reload enabled.
6injected.js:1 Provider initialised
injected.js:1 TronWeb: 'tronWeb.sidechain' is deprecated and may be removed in the future. Please use the 'sunweb' sdk instead. For more information, see: https://github.com/tronprotocol/sun-network/tree/develop/js-sdk
e @ injected.js:1
3content.js:1 Deprecation warning: tabReply will be removed
(анонимная) @ content.js:1
Показать ещё 1 фрейм
Свернуть
injected.js:1 TronLink initiated
Notes Hunter.loader.js:1 You can reduce startup time if you configure your web server to add "Content-Encoding: gzip" response header when serving "Build/Notes Hunter.framework.js.unityweb" file.
v2:sourcemap:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at v2:sourcemap:1:116680
    at t (v2:sourcemap:1:113012)
Notes Hunter.loader.js:1 You can reduce startup time if you configure your web server to add "Content-Encoding: gzip" response header when serving "Build/Notes Hunter.wasm.unityweb" file.
Notes Hunter.loader.js:1 You can reduce startup time if you configure your web server to add "Content-Encoding: gzip" response header when serving "Build/Notes Hunter.data.unityweb" file.
Notes Hunter.loader.js:1 [UnityCache] 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/Build/Notes%20Hunter.data.unityweb' successfully downloaded and stored in the indexedDB cache
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 navigator.mediaDevices support available
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 [UnityMemory] Configuration Parameters - Can be set up in boot.config

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-allocator-temp-initial-block-size-main=262144"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-allocator-temp-initial-block-size-worker=262144"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-nav-mesh-worker=65536"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-audio-worker=65536"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-background-worker=32768"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-gfx-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-gfx-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-cache-allocator-block-size=4194304"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-typetree-allocator-block-size=2097152"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-profiler-allocator-block-size=16777216"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-profiler-editor-allocator-block-size=1048576"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-main=4194304"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size=2097152"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size-background=1048576"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10     "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-reduction-small-platforms=262144"

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 [Physics::Module] Initialized SinglethreadedJobDispatcher.

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Loading player data from data.unity3d

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Initialize engine version: 2022.3.15f1 (b58023a2b463)

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 [Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path UnitySubsystems

Notes Hunter.loader.js:1 Creating WebGL 2.0 context.
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Renderer: WebKit WebGL

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Vendor:   WebKit

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Version:  OpenGL ES 3.0 (WebGL 2.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 Chromium))

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 GLES:     3

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10  EXT_color_buffer_float EXT_color_buffer_half_float EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2 EXT_float_blend EXT_texture_compression_bptc EXT_texture_compression_rgtc EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic EXT_texture_norm16 KHR_parallel_shader_compile OES_draw_buffers_indexed OES_texture_float_linear OVR_multiview2 WEBGL_clip_cull_distance WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc_srgb WEBGL_debug_renderer_info WEBGL_debug_shaders WEBGL_lose_context WEBGL_multi_draw WEBGL_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2 GL_EXT_float_blend GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_norm16 GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_WEBGL_clip_cull_distance GL_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc GL_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc_srgb GL_WEBGL_debug_renderer_info GL_WEBGL_debug_shaders GL_WEBGL_lose_context GL_WEBGL_multi_dra

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 w GL_WEBGL_provoking_vertex

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.0 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 3.0> ; Context handle 1

28The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. <URL>
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 ERROR: Shader 
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Hidden/VoxelizeShader shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Input Manager initialize...

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Button') is missing!

_JS_Log_Dump @ db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10
v2:sourcemap:1 Tree prefab at index 0 is missing.

console.error @ v2:sourcemap:1
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 [Physics::Module] Initialized SinglethreadedJobDispatcher.

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 UnloadTime: 6.799999 ms

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Init Envir inGame

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Init Storage inGame

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 No Saves

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Reset Save Progress

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Init Auth inGame

v2:sourcemap:1 Failed init player data

console.error @ v2:sourcemap:1
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Init Lang inGame

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Init Payments inGame

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Get Payments

v2:sourcemap:1 Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at Hr (v2:sourcemap:1:92751)
    at console.error (v2:sourcemap:1:94831)
    at _JS_Log_Dump (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:38677)
    at 090d8ada:0x1f56bb2
    at 090d8ada:0x1f56e68
    at 090d8ada:0x1f57f52
    at 090d8ada:0x1f57e53
    at 090d8ada:0x1f5778f
    at 090d8ada:0x1bf3270
    at 090d8ada:0x1e77f5f
    at 090d8ada:0x1e85220
    at 090d8ada:0x16c31cb
    at 090d8ada:0x16c469e
    at 090d8ada:0x16c5ab5
    at 090d8ada:0x16c5c6c
    at 090d8ada:0x1e62d85
    at 090d8ada:0x1f81a7d
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82097
    at Module._main (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:342263)
    at callMain (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:446630)
    at doRun (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:447077)
    at run (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:447249)
    at runCaller (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:446289)
    at Object.removeRunDependency (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:17133)
    at Notes Hunter.loader.js:1:43652
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
v2:sourcemap:1 Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at Hr (v2:sourcemap:1:92751)
    at console.error (v2:sourcemap:1:94831)
    at _JS_Log_Dump (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:38677)
    at 090d8ada:0x1f56bb2
    at 090d8ada:0x1f56e68
    at 090d8ada:0x1f57f52
    at 090d8ada:0x1f57e53
    at 090d8ada:0x1f5778f
    at 090d8ada:0x1eb7d0b
    at 090d8ada:0x10b3745
    at 090d8ada:0xe270e1
    at 090d8ada:0x10b3e5e
    at 090d8ada:0x13fdc06
    at 090d8ada:0x13fdaa3
    at 090d8ada:0x14dd64d
    at 090d8ada:0x14eb5d8
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82f6f
    at invoke_iiii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:425248)
    at 090d8ada:0x14ea670
    at 090d8ada:0x14eb8bb
    at 090d8ada:0xf36d9
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82fa3
    at invoke_iiiii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:425409)
    at 090d8ada:0x11bd873
    at 090d8ada:0x11b068e
    at 090d8ada:0x14037ef
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82f61
    at invoke_vii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:424812)
    at 090d8ada:0x13fec66
    at 090d8ada:0x14019ce
    at 090d8ada:0x14b6697
    at 090d8ada:0x14eb5d8
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82f6f
    at invoke_iiii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:425248)
    at 090d8ada:0x14ea670
    at 090d8ada:0xe39e5
    at 090d8ada:0x1f322c4
    at 090d8ada:0x1ea0f29
    at 090d8ada:0x1632ca5
    at 090d8ada:0x15f9607
    at 090d8ada:0x15f9b4b
    at 090d8ada:0x1e8bf69
    at 090d8ada:0x15f957e
    at 090d8ada:0x1e77d55
    at 090d8ada:0x1e76e7f
    at 090d8ada:0x16c4b77
    at 090d8ada:0x16c47ac
    at 090d8ada:0x16c5b43
    at 090d8ada:0x16c5c6c
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
mc.yandex.ru/watch/undefined?page-url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5500%2Findex.html&page-ref=&charset=utf-8&site-info=%7B%22borrowParams%22%3A%7B%22tmpPlayTime5%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 До запроса к показу рекламы в середине игры 60,0 сек.

db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Init Leaderbords inGame

v2:sourcemap:1 CRASH Init Leaderboard:  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getLeaderboards')
console.error @ v2:sourcemap:1
v2:sourcemap:1 Failed - Game Ready
console.error @ v2:sourcemap:1
index.html:191 Init Game Success
v2:sourcemap:1 Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at Hr (v2:sourcemap:1:92751)
    at console.error (v2:sourcemap:1:94831)
    at InitLeaderboard (index.html:297:25)
    at _InitLeaderboard (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:23640)
    at 090d8ada:0x1401b10
    at 090d8ada:0x14b6697
    at 090d8ada:0x14eb5d8
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82f6f
    at invoke_iiii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:425248)
    at 090d8ada:0x14ea670
    at 090d8ada:0xe39e5
    at 090d8ada:0x1f322c4
    at 090d8ada:0x1ea1148
    at 090d8ada:0x15f7bb8
    at 090d8ada:0x15f9284
    at 090d8ada:0x1e8cd33
    at 090d8ada:0x1e6b29e
    at 090d8ada:0x15bd67d
    at 090d8ada:0x15bd6f1
    at 090d8ada:0x1f659b7
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82fab
    at browserIterationFunc (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:233112)
    at callUserCallback (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:186681)
    at Object.runIter (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:187921)
    at Browser_mainLoop_runner (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:186217)
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
v2:sourcemap:1 Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at Hr (v2:sourcemap:1:92751)
    at console.error (v2:sourcemap:1:94831)
    at _GameReadyAPI_js (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:22485)
    at 090d8ada:0x13fe475
    at 090d8ada:0x14dd64d
    at 090d8ada:0x14eb5d8
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82f6f
    at invoke_iiii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:425248)
    at 090d8ada:0x14ea670
    at 090d8ada:0x14eb8bb
    at 090d8ada:0xf36d9
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82fa3
    at invoke_iiiii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:425409)
    at 090d8ada:0x11bd873
    at 090d8ada:0x11b068e
    at 090d8ada:0x14037ef
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82f61
    at invoke_vii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:424812)
    at 090d8ada:0x13ff02e
    at 090d8ada:0x1401b2f
    at 090d8ada:0x14b6697
    at 090d8ada:0x14eb5d8
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82f6f
    at invoke_iiii (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:425248)
    at 090d8ada:0x14ea670
    at 090d8ada:0xe39e5
    at 090d8ada:0x1f322c4
    at 090d8ada:0x1ea1148
    at 090d8ada:0x15f7bb8
    at 090d8ada:0x15f9284
    at 090d8ada:0x1e8cd33
    at 090d8ada:0x1e6b29e
    at 090d8ada:0x15bd67d
    at 090d8ada:0x15bd6f1
    at 090d8ada:0x1f659b7
    at 090d8ada:0x1f82fab
    at browserIterationFunc (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:233112)
    at callUserCallback (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:186681)
    at Object.runIter (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:187921)
    at Browser_mainLoop_runner (db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10:186217)
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
256[.WebGL-00007D440406C000] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: It is undefined behaviour to use a uniform buffer that is too small.
index.html:1 WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
v2:sourcemap:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:111123)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:15298)
db4de72b-8b6f-44a1-9b62-0bc70647559d:10 Trying to get length of sound which is not loaded.
v2:sourcemap:1 Unhandled rejection: SecurityError: The user has exited the lock before this request was completed. Object
console.error @ v2:sourcemap:1
v2:sourcemap:1 Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at Object.Hr [as logger] (v2:sourcemap:1:92751)
    at Object._postError (v2:sourcemap:1:94509)
    at Object._unsafeHandlePromiseRejectionEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93816)
    at Object._unsafeHandleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93320)
    at Object._handleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93164)
    at Object.handleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93113)
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user has exited the lock before this request was completed.
v2:sourcemap:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:111123)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:15298)
v2:sourcemap:1 Unhandled rejection: SecurityError: The user has exited the lock before this request was completed. Object
console.error @ v2:sourcemap:1
v2:sourcemap:1 Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at Object.Hr [as logger] (v2:sourcemap:1:92751)
    at Object._postError (v2:sourcemap:1:94509)
    at Object._unsafeHandlePromiseRejectionEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93816)
    at Object._unsafeHandleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93320)
    at Object._handleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93164)
    at Object.handleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93113)
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user has exited the lock before this request was completed.
v2:sourcemap:1 Unhandled rejection: SecurityError: The user has exited the lock before this request was completed. Object
console.error @ v2:sourcemap:1
v2:sourcemap:1 Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at Object.Hr [as logger] (v2:sourcemap:1:92751)
    at Object._postError (v2:sourcemap:1:94509)
    at Object._unsafeHandlePromiseRejectionEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93816)
    at Object._unsafeHandleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93320)
    at Object._handleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93164)
    at Object.handleEvent (v2:sourcemap:1:93113)
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user has exited the lock before this request was completed.
3v2:sourcemap:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:111123)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:15298)
mc.yandex.ru/watch/undefined?page-url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5500%2Findex.html&page-ref=&charset=utf-8&site-info=%7B%22borrowParams%22%3A%7B%22tmpPlayTime60%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
2v2:sourcemap:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:111123)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:15298)
6v2:sourcemap:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:111123)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:15298)
postToParent @ v2:sourcemap:1
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
(анонимная) @ v2:sourcemap:1
4v2:sourcemap:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No parent to post message
    at f.postToParent (v2:sourcemap:1:9214)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:111123)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v2:sourcemap:1:15298)```


It will be difficult for us to help you troubleshoot this issue without a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Can you make a small project that demonstrates the issue, and edit your question to walk us through the steps to reproduce it? Once we can see the issue locally, we can test potential answers to be sure they'll work for you.

There are many error messages in your console log - for example, missing scripts, missing prefabs, unsupported shaders, failure to initialize player data, "no parent to post message", etc. You should read through the console log and try to fix each of the errors. That will help you narrow down the problem.

I figured out what the problem was. In the unity editor, postprocessing works fine, but in the build webgl project, all postprocessing is disabled. But I still haven't been able to solve it unfortunately

I looked, in principle, postprocessing does not work for me on a build project
